# RestrictedPython: get print output when printing from within a function

Tags: python, plone, sandbox, zope

I'm running the following code using `RestrictedPython` (using `safeglobals['_print_'] = PrintCollector` and `compile_restricted_exec`/`exec(compiled_code, safe_globals, locals)`).

```
def foo():
    print 'bar'

print '123'
foo()
```

After the code executed, I can obtain the print output via `locals.pop('_print')` which holds an instance of `PrintCollector`, but only for the `print '123'` statement that is outside of the function. When debugging this, I see two instances of `PrintCollector` being created, presumably for the two contexts (module level and function) in which the `print` statement is being used.

However, I can't find a way to access the `PrintCollector` instance that was created when entering `def foo()`. The documentation for `RestrictedPython` is quite scant which is why I ask here for any advice on how one could access the function's print output the `RestrictedPython`-way.

Example:

```
from RestrictedPython import compile_restricted
from RestrictedPython.PrintCollector import PrintCollector

_print_ = PrintCollector

code_string = """
def foo():
    print 'bar'

print '123'
foo()
"""

loc = {'_print_': PrintCollector, '_getattr_': getattr}
compiled_code = compile_restricted(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code, loc)
loc['_print']()
```

Comment: Providing a complete code-example for replication would be helpful.

Comment: Your example was ok (except for returning the printed values which I was hoping not to do). Anyway, I updated my question with the ideal code that I'd like to execute and get both printouts from.

Comment: Thanks for updating your example. If I prepend the last line with a print-statement, I get the result you report, but cannot help further with the way you'd expect things to work.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Here's how I'd debug restricted code without using print-statements:

```
from RestrictedPython import compile_restricted
from RestrictedPython.PrintCollector import PrintCollector

_print_ = PrintCollector

code_string = """
def foo():
    global debug_inner
    debug_inner = 'bar'

foo()
debug_outer = '123'
results = [debug_inner, debug_outer]
"""

compiled_code = compile_restricted(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code)
print results

# Output should be:
# >>> ['bar', '123']
```

---

Old answer:

Following the example you're giving, the function needs to return the `printed`-variable and also be executed within a print-statement, as explained in these docs:
https://code.activestate.com/pypm/restrictedpython/#print

Example:

```
from RestrictedPython import compile_restricted
from RestrictedPython.PrintCollector import PrintCollector


_print_ = PrintCollector

code_string = """

def hello_world():
    print 'Hello inner world!'
    return printed

print 'Hello outer world!' # print a string

print hello_world()        # print return of function

results = printed          # fetch printed in a global

"""

# Compile and excecute restricted code:
compiled_code = compile_restricted(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code)

# Now we have `results` available as a global:
print results.split('\n') # convert string into list of lines

# We should get:
# >>> ['Hello inner world!', 'Hello outer world!', '', '']
```

Comment: The requirement is to allow running of untrusted code and (primitive) debugging through print statements. Your code works fine and resolves the issue I was seeing by returning `printed` from the function and printing it again. However, in normal Python code, the `print` output of `hello_world` would just appear in the output without requiring to print it again from the module level. The question is whether it's done like this for some specific (security?) reason or whether it is a bug that the (outer module) `PrintCollector` isn't collecting the function printouts.

Comment: I don't know, if it's a bug or a feature. Updated answer with debugging-alternative which does not require the function to return `printed` as it's probably supposed to return something else :-) HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why _print_ needs to be a factory, but given that it does if you want a single output accumulator that spans multiple print() calls and scopes, just define your own class that employs a static variable to accumulate all of the output:

```
class PrintCollector:

    output = []

    def __init__(self, _getattr_=None):
        self._getattr_ = _getattr_

    def write(self, text):
        PrintCollector.output.append(text)

    def __call__(self):
        return ''.join(PrintCollector.output)

    def _call_print(self, *objects, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('file', None) is None:
            kwargs['file'] = self
        else:
            self._getattr_(kwargs['file'], 'write')

        print(*objects, **kwargs)
```

You can then grab/print all of output as follows:

```
print("".join(PrintCollector.output))
```

Of course general warnings/caveats about static variables apply

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem and I find that there are two instances of PrintCollector being created too.

So I inherit the class PrintCollector and make it singleton. The problem solved.

```
def singleton(cls):
    _instance = {}
    def inner(t):
        if cls not in _instance:
            _instance[cls] = cls(t)
        return _instance[cls]
    return inner

@singleton
class SafePrintCollector(PrintCollector):
    pass
```

But if you want to run RestrictedPython multiple times, you need to add a reset method to clear last print output.